# take 1 line output from command, split it and put it in a new file line by line

Tags: awk, grep

If I get an output from a command that outputs information in the following way:

```
{"value1":"value2","value3":"value4","value5":10001,"value6":999.99,}
```

Is there a way to pass that value to grep/awk and have it create a new file that puts the information in to a file with 1 value per line

so ideally the output I would be looking for in the file would read

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5: 10001
value6: 999.99
```

appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Euh, that output would be pretty broken.

Comment: Why does the output not have `value1: value2` on the first line, and `value3: value4` on the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input looks like JSON. If it is you should probably parse it as JSON using an existing library for a language of your choice (I would use Ruby myself).

But if the input format is simple (e.g., the quoted strings don't contain anything that would warrant complex parsing), you may be able to get away with something simple along the lines of:

```
awk -F , '{ gsub(/(^{)|(}$)|"/, ""); for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i }'
```

(Note that this does not actually do exactly what you want and it breaks if there are commas inside the quoted strings. Modify as necessary if you go down this path.)

Comment: Thanks your right it is JSON, I cannot change the output format as it is returned from an api call. that awk line returns near enough what I need, certainly enough to work with, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are expecting a bit strange output... anyway, with `sed`:

```
$ echo '{"value1":"value2","value3":"value4","value5":10001,"value6":999.99,}' | sed '{ s/[\{"\}]//g ; s/,/\n/g ; s/:\([^0-9]\)/\n\1/g; s/:\([0-9]\)/: \1/g}'                                                                     
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5: 10001
value6: 999.99
```